# What are the RGB or HEX values of the default theme colors in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, color-scheme

I need to capture the color values for the scheme colors (i.e. accent1, accent2,....) in a Microsoft Word 2010 document. I have tried searching on the internet a lot but couldn't find any answer.

Can any one help me with the reference for these colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though i didn't get any answers for my question but I eventually found the answer and thought the share it for others' use.

The theme color references can be found in the `word/theme/theme1.xml` file, however these references can not be directly used as the color values. First they need to be mapped from `word/settings.xml` file under `w:clrSchemeMapping` tag.

The following are the Hex colour values for Microsoft Word 2010 default theme from `theme1.xml` file:

```
     dk1="000000"
     lt1="FFFFFF"
     dk2="1F497D"
     lt2="EEECE1"
     accent1="4F81BD"
     accent2="C0504D"
     accent3="9BBB59"
     accent4="8064A2"
     accent5="4BACC6"
     accent6="F79646"
     hlink="0000FF"
     folHlink="800080"
```