# In Word VBA, how can I correctly set font colours that use the theme colour tints?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a VBA macro which sets the colour of one piece of text to match the colour another piece of text. I am having difficulty when the text is coloured with a tint of one of the theme colours.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeRangeColour()

Dim rSourceColourRange As Range
Set rSourceColourRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=10, End:=20)

Dim rDestinationRange As Range
Set rDestinationRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=30, End:=40)

rDestinationRange.Font.Color = rSourceColourRange.Font.Color


End Sub
```

I'm using `.Font.Color`, although it's undocumented, because `.Font.ColorIndex` doesn't seem to work correctly with custom colours. If there is another property I should be using instead, please let me know.

This works fine for custom colours, standard colours and basic theme colours. When the text is coloured with a tint of one of the theme colours, the destination text is changed to the theme colour with no tint. How can I get the tint along with the colour?

Comment: The tint is probably obtained by something like brightness or saturation, so youll have to set that as well

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857317/what-are-the-rgb-or-hex-values-of-the-default-theme-colors-in-microsoft-word-201

Comment: @Luuklag thanks. Can you tell me what property of the Font object I need to use to get brightness or saturation? I can't figure it out from the documentation. Is this another undocumented property?

Comment: You'll need to work through the various Font properties to locate what it is you need, exactly. There's `TextColor`, `Brightness`, `RGB`, `Glow`, `Shadow`, `Shading`, `Reflection`, for example. Inspect the values for various properties until you hit on what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `.Font.Color` certainly used to work, at least in WD2007 - WD2013. It returned a long value that was either the specific RGB, for non-theme colours,  or the equivalent of the HEX value of the combination of theme color and tint (or shade). Tony Jollans wrote a [detailed article](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php) for Word 2007 that gives all the gory details of theme colours.

`.Font.Color` is undocumented because it has been deprecated and from testing in Word 365 I can confirm that it no longer works like it used to. It now only returns the theme colour not the tint or shade.

@Cindy Meister suggested `.Font.TextColor` which sounds as though it should give the values you seek. Unfortunately, although it returns a `ColorFormat` object complete with `.ObjectThemeColor`, `.Brightness` and `.TintAndShade` properties, the only valid information you will get is from `.ObjectThemeColor`, so that will not give you what you need.

To get *all* the information you require you have to set logic aside and examine `.Font.Fill.ForeColor`. (Like, *really*?! Font has a *fill* colour??) This will also return a `ColorFormat` object but this time all the properties return valid data.

You should therefore change:

```
rDestinationRange.Font.Color = rSourceColourRange.Font.Color
```

to:

```
With rDestinationRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
    .ObjectThemeColor = rSourceColourRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor
    .Brightness = rSourceColourRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness
End With
```

For completeness, the `.Brightness` property returns a value of -1 for 100% (i.e. no tint or shade), 0.6 for 40% lighter, 0.4 for 60% lighter, etc. Negative values are used for shades with -0.75 representing 25% darker and -0.5 50% darker.

It is also possible to set `.Brightness` to values that don't correspond to those in the palette, e.g. 0.25 for 75% lighter, or -0.9 for 10% darker.