# How to get RGB colors or HEX colors out of word using VB

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find a way to pull information out of a Word document so that I have the Font, Font Size, Font Color of each of the Headings. I tried pulling it multiple ways, in the end I created a document that had the word Heading ! in it.

I am able to get a color number, but when I convert it to RGB it doesn't represent the right color. I am getting the font color red versus White. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

This is in VB

```
Sub FindHeading1Properties()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim fontColor As Long
    Dim fontName As String
    Dim newDoc As Document

    ' Set variables
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set searchRange = doc.Content
    Set newDoc = Documents.Add

    ' Find the word "HEADING 1" in the document (case-insensitive)
    With searchRange.Find
        .Text = "HEADING 1"
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            ' Get the font properties of the found range
            Set foundRange = searchRange.Duplicate
            fontSize = foundRange.Font.Size
            fontColor = foundRange.Font.Color
            fontName = foundRange.Font.Name

            ' Convert the font color to RGB values
            Dim red As Integer
            Dim green As Integer
            Dim blue As Integer
            red = (fontColor Mod 256)
            green = ((fontColor \ 256) Mod 256)
            blue = ((fontColor \ 65536) Mod 256)

            ' Print the RGB values on the new document
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Font Size: " & fontSize & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Red: " & red & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Green: " & green & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Blue: " & blue & vbCrLf
        Else
            MsgBox "The word 'HEADING 1' was not found in the document."
        End If
    End With

    ' Activate the new document
    newDoc.Activate
    ' Scroll to the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    ' Clear the variables
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set searchRange = Nothing
    Set foundRange = Nothing
    Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is a link to the word document: https://www.dropbox.com/t/9oc88vkiN7OWjQ9T

You will see for Heading 1 it should be 255,255,255

Thanks!

I tried different methods and calculations. I can not get the output to be correct

I am always able to get a number -- usually negative like

Font Size: 11
Font Color: -603914241  <-- should be white
Font Name: Calibri

```
Sub GetHeading1Color()

'Declare variables
Dim doc As Document
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim run As Run
Dim color As Long

'Set variables
Set doc = ActiveDocument

'Get the first paragraph in the document
Set para = doc.Paragraphs(1)

'Get the first run in the paragraph
Set run = para.Runs(1)

'Get the color of the run
color = run.Font.ColorIndex

'Display the color
MsgBox "The color of the Heading 1 style is " & color

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you use `Mod` at all when singling out individual bytes of a `Long`? You use `And` for that.

Comment: VB?(VB6 VB.NET) or VBA ? They are different. Please acknowledge them in your tags and header, and in your lines of text. make sure that they are not wrong.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55927242/5211752 for details on colors. The link to Tony Jollans website is still valid and you should find the conversion code you need there.

Comment: I did try an AND instead of MOD but that didn't work either  I am in VBA I am running it as a macro

Comment: I did look at the Stack by Tony, but I only could see how to take a color in Word and apply it to another element in word, I want to know the HEX number (or close that can be used as a browser color)

Comment: You need to change `fontColor = foundRange.Font.Color` to `fontColor = foundRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB`. Otherwise your code seems to work on a document I created. However, to make it work on your document, I had to upgrade it to the latest format. It was giving me *runtime error 4605 "this command is not available"*. What version of word are you running?

Comment: Clearly you didn’t read *all* of Tony Jollans article. The code to convert to Hex and extract the red, green and blue values is all in that article.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you, I did read the article and in fact tried the code. It kind of works in XLS with some modification, but I have never been able to get it to work in word. There seems to be an error in '''Sub Colours2()
    Dim bgColor As Long
    bgColor = Selection.Cells(1).Interior.Color'''   The code sent earlier still gives negative RGB numbers. Which of course can not happen

Comment: @MarkPinsley - your question is about colors in Word, which is why I pointed you to an article written by a Word MVP about colors in Word. If you want to apply it to Excel then, obviously, modification will be required, especially as theme colors are treated differently in Excel's object model.

Answer (score 1):

Try these functions:

```
Function colorToRGB(color As Long) As Variant
  Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
  Dim divisor As Long: divisor = 16 ^ 2

  r = (color Mod divisor)
  g = (color Mod divisor ^ 2 - r)
  b = (color Mod divisor ^ 3 - r - g)

  colorToRGB = Array(r, g / divisor, b / divisor ^ 2)
End Function

Function colorToHex(color As Long) As String
  Dim rgbs As Variant
  rgbs = colorToRGB(color)
  colorToHex = "#" & pad0(Hex(rgbs(0))) & pad0(Hex(rgbs(1))) & pad0(Hex(rgbs(2)))
End Function

Function pad0(hexNum As String) As String
  If Len(hexNum) = 1 Then pad0 = "0" & hexNum Else pad0 = hexNum
End Function
```

You can use them in your code as follows:

```
Sub FindHeading1Properties()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Dim fontSize As Integer
    Dim fontColor As Long
    Dim fontName As String
    Dim newDoc As Document

    ' Set variables
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set searchRange = doc.Content
    Set newDoc = Documents.Add

    ' Find the word "HEADING 1" in the document (case-insensitive)
    With searchRange.Find
        .Text = "HEADING 1"
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            ' Get the font properties of the found range
            Set foundRange = searchRange.Duplicate
            fontSize = foundRange.Font.Size
            fontColor = foundRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            fontName = foundRange.Font.Name
            foundRange.Select

            Dim rgbs As Variant
            Dim hexColor As String
            rgbs = colorToRGB(fontColor)
            hexColor = colorToHex(fontColor)

            ' Print the RGB values on the new document
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Font Size: " & fontSize & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Red: " & rgbs(0) & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Green: " & rgbs(1) & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Blue: " & rgbs(2) & vbCrLf
            newDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Hex: " & hexColor & vbCrLf
        Else
            MsgBox "The word 'HEADING 1' was not found in the document."
        End If
    End With

    ' Activate the new document
    newDoc.Activate
    ' Scroll to the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    ' Clear the variables
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set searchRange = Nothing
    Set foundRange = Nothing
    Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly simple! Just replace

```
fontColor = foundRange.Font.Color
```

with

```
fontColor = foundRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

then you'll get them.