# How to Identify Long or Hex Colour for Selected Cells with VBA? Use Font.TextColor or Hex(cell.Font.color), or?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fonts, identify

How to use VBA excel to report Font Colour Code or Hex for Selected Cells ?
The below 1. sequence and 2. Function work great for obtaining Shading Colours.
But does not work when substituting the word “Shade” with “Font”, in the third routine below,
I was not able to use Font.TextColor nor Hex(cell.Font.color) to identify the font colour.
Thumbs up to designer of the Shade Colour Code in 1. and 2. , great if we can do the same in 3. with fonts.

1

```
Sub ShadClipbdCopyHex_CtlSftT()
'   Got Shade Hex, need font details as well
'   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344840/how-to-get-rgb-colors-or-hex-colors-out-of-word-using-vb
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ShadeColor As Long
    Dim fontName As String
    Dim ShadeHex As String
            ShadeColor = ActiveCell.Interior.color
            ShadeHex = ConvertLongToHex(ShadeColor)
'            fontName = ActiveCell.Font.Name
        Clipboard ShadeHex
        Debug.Print ShadeHex ', fontName
End Sub
```

2

```
Public Function ConvertLongToHex(lColor As Long) As String
    Dim sRed As String, sGreen As String, sBlue As String
    sRed = Right("00" & Hex(lColor Mod 256), 2)
    sGreen = Right("00" & Hex(lColor \ 2 ^ 8 Mod 256), 2)
    sBlue = Right("00" & Hex(lColor \ 2 ^ 16 Mod 256), 2)
    ConvertLongToHex = "#" & sRed & sGreen & sBlue
End Function
```

3

```
Sub FontClipbdCopyHex()
'   CP 45Mar24 Got Shade Hex above, adapting to Fonts substituting Font.TextColor
'   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Font.TextColor

    Dim FontColor As Long
    Dim fontName As String
    Dim FontHex As String

            FontColor = ActiveCell.Font.TextColor
            FontHex = ConvertLongToHex(FontColor)
'            fontName = ActiveCell.Font.Name
        Clipboard FontHex
        Debug.Print FontHex ', fontName
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried `ActiveCell.Font.Color`?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell.Font.Color` will return a number representing the colour.

Note, however, that it is returning a BGR value, not an RGB value. This seems odd given that colour values are set using the RGB() function, but in fact that function returns a number representing a BGR value.

For example, the following code

```vb
Sub test()
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Debug.Print Hex(RGB(0, 0, 255)) & ", " & RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Debug.Print Hex(ActiveCell.Font.Color) & ", " & ActiveCell.Font.Color
End Sub
```

produces the following in the intermediate window:

```
FF0000, 16711680
FF0000, 16711680
```

In this example, the text colour in that cell is blue, not red.

Comment: Thanks Peter, Brilliant, obvious ActiveCell.Font.Color a very simple fix. Dropping the "text" from ActiveCell.Font.TextColor (that I was trying to use), which was just copied from some other VBA routine.
I can't cast a vote, first point was great. Office hours, busy, no time to follow other points made.